# How to insert array in mySQL using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

This code, using post as object, is working.

```
let post = {id: 1, name: 'Terminal 1'};
db.query('INSERT INTO terminal SET ?', post);
```

This code, using post as array, is not working.

```
let post = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Terminal 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Terminal 2'}
];
db.query('INSERT INTO terminal SET ?', post);
or 
db.query('INSERT INTO terminal SET ?', [post]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call query for every object in array using for..of cycle:

```
let post = [
{id: 1, name: 'Terminal 1'},
{id: 2, name: 'Terminal 2'}
]
for (let object of post) {
db.query('INSERT INTO terminal SET ?', object)
}
```

Comment: It is an option, but I'd preffer to solve it like a bulk insert to reduce request to the data base